# How to handle tap out of custom view frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom view with custom popup on it (added as subview).
When I'm opening this popup it's frame goes out of parent view frame.
And I can't handle user interaction on the outside popup view.
How can I fix it?

[image]

I thought about this plan:
 1. Add custom view on superview;
 2. Add custom popup on superview (right the position where it should be on custom view)

But i think it isn't right way.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I haven't tried it yet, but you might have luck with adding a custom view on the superview and overriding `pointInside:withEvent:`.

I'm thinking the superview is recognizing that the tap doesn't occur inside its own frame, so it won't even check its subviews. But if you override `pointInside:withEvent:` you can check that the tap location is inside the subviews frame regardless of whether it's inside the superview's frame.

If that doesn't work, you might have to override `hitTest:withEvent:` also (or instead of). I can try to work out an example if you need more direction than that.

Answer (score 0):

This Technical Q&A  might help you out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is actually the right approach: you should have a superview (it can be transparent (clear color)) that contains both the custom view and the popup inside of its frame.

On iOS, touch events are sent to a receiver at a low level in your visual hierarchy (I believe this is your Window to be specific). This receiver calls HitTest on its subviews to figure out which one to forward the event to. This happens recursively until the HitTest fails on all of a view's subviews. Then the parent of those subviews handles (or doesn't handle) the touch event.

But before the HitTest implementation even starts calling HitTest on the subviews, it calls PointInside on the superview. If PointInside returns false for the touch point, then HitTest returns null.

So overriding PointInside on the class that you call SuperView may solve the problem you're facing, but not necessarily. You may need to override PointInside on the superview of SuperView, and then on that view's superview, and so on. This is not a good solution, it is brittle and hacky. Overriding PointInside does have its uses, but this isn't one.

So try to keep all of your views within the bounds of their superview, even if you have to make a transparent superview that has no other reason to exist other than to contain other views. That's fine.